# OrderBy text using CAST

Tags: sql

I want to  order this query with CAST but, really ,I don´t know how to.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN TotalDue>= 0 and TotalDue<= 99 then '1: 0-99' 
WHEN TotalDue >= 100 and TotalDue<= 499 then '2: 100-499'
WHEN TotalDue>= 500 and TotalDue<= 1000 then '3: 500-1000'
WHEN TotalDue>1000 and TotalDue<= 9999 then '4: 1000-9999'
WHEN TotalDue>10000 then '5: 10000 en adelante'
END AS Rango,COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS 'Cantidad de Órdenes', SUM (TotalDue) AS 'Valor Total'
FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader GROUP BY 
CASE WHEN TotalDue>= 0 and TotalDue<= 99 then '1: 0-99' 
WHEN TotalDue >= 100 and TotalDue<= 499 then '2: 100-499'
WHEN TotalDue>= 500 and TotalDue<= 1000 then '3: 500-1000'
WHEN TotalDue>1000 and TotalDue<= 9999 then '4: 1000-9999'
WHEN TotalDue>10000 then '5: 10000 en adelante'
END ORDER BY Rango
```

I put "1" for the fist case, "2" for the second, etc to solved it, but I need to order by numerically
Can, someone, help me?
TKS!

Comment: Do you have sample data?

Comment: Hi! First of all, tks for your answer. 
Tell me if this is what you need. Right now, the code I wrote before, bring back: Rango Cantidad de Órdenes Valor Total
1: 0-99 3 175,3283
2: 100-499 2 390,3744
3: 500-1000 3 2246,3867
4: 1000-9999 10 30455,3781
5: 10000 en adelante 14 923036,1274 Hope this is what you ask to me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, tks for your answer.
Tell me if this is what you need. Right now, the code I wrote before, bring back:

Rango   Cantidad de Órdenes Valor Total
1: 0-99 3   175,3283
2: 100-499  2   390,3744
3: 500-1000 3   2246,3867
4: 1000-9999    10  30455,3781
5: 10000 en adelante    14  923036,1274 Hope this is what you ask to me.

Comment: Do not post additional information as new answer, edit your question and include all relevant information there.